# Calling another Activity

Tags: android

Hi I'm developing an Android app but I have a problem calling another Activity.

Actually my app has one login and user comes to home screen upto here its fine but I need to load some other pages while clicking the buttons on the home screen here is the problem:

```
package com.example.finance_planner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Home extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        Button overviewbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaddincome);

        overviewbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Home.this,Addincome.class));
        }
        });
     }

}
```

Comment: remove the first on create function

Comment: What exactly IS your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your first onCreate method. Also, you must declare your `Addincome` activity in the `Manifest`.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Home extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        Button overviewbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaddincome);
        overviewbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Home.this,Addincome.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have defined the Addincome activity in Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it because of image button  we have to defien image button rather than normal button

```
ImageButton mybut=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaddincome);
```